# Online password storage with roles and permissions?

Tags: security, password-manager, encryption, sharing

I would like to provide a team of developers a way to share passwords to collectively used services.

Software requirements:

1. Since the team is distributed, the passwords should be accessible via web.
2. I would like to assign roles to the users, so that users with role A can access all the passwords and users with role B can access only some passwords.
3. I would like to be able to lock any user or change the user's role at any time.
4. Some meaningful security built into this software application would be nice.
5. GPL/Apache licensed and other open-source software is preferred (we can self-host).

Could you recommend some online group password storage software according to the requirements?

Comment: Does it need to have a comfortable interface, or would CLI (Command Line Interface) be OK?

Comment: This would be considered bad practice due to tracking accountability especially if/when a shared password got compromised. It may also contravene use agreements for some services. I think this means that it is unlikely you will find such an application written by a group that understands the security implications of what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

[LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) should do the trick. It meets all of your [sharing needs](https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/features/sharing/). There is also an [enterprise edition](https://lastpass.com/enterprise_overview.php) with more coworker/employee login sharing features (but I've never tried that out at all).

***Security note #1:*** While this is secure from external snooping the person it is shared with can get the password (even if it is hidden with a little bit of work)). So **definitely** use a unique password for each service (you **should** do that all the time but many people don't).

***Security note #2:*** Once shared although you can unshare the password you cannot count on it not being known even if set to hidden (due to #1). So to truely unshare you will have to change login credentials. The [enterprise edition](https://lastpass.com/enterprise_overview.php) intro-page seems to **imply** that it is developed to somehow avoid that but if you read the docs closer it **does not actually avoid that** at all.

As well it is:

- *Cross-platform:* (Windows, Mac & Linux) *and* cross-browser compatible (all 5 common browsers)! Also has an Android and iOS app.
- *Very Secure:* Lastpass is very secure; of course generally it is only as secure as your master password. However you can enable multi-factor authentication (might need premium I can't remember - since I don't have cell signal usually I haven't bothered to set that up for anything despite the benefits).
- *Fairly cheap:* Free version available. Premium version is  $12/year.

Lastpass is also more than just a password app; you can securely (ie with encryption) store important documents and notes and credit card/address details as well.

To go over your requirements:

1. *Since the team is distributed, the passwords should be accessible via web:* Client-software on each computer. I don't know if it has a web interface - I've never used anything but the client at any rate.
2. *I would like to assign roles to the users, so that users with role A can access all the passwords and users with role B can access only some passwords:* With the enterprise edition you can definitely do this.
3. *I would like to be able to lock any user or change the user's role at any time:* Yes - **but see note #2**
4. *Some meaningful security built into this software application would be nice:* Pretty good - obviously there are some flaws/loopholes (see notes #1/#2).
5. *GPL/Apache licensed and other open-source software is preferred (we can self-host). **No**. Unfortunately not.